How to fix "The installation of this Visual Studio instance is not completed" for Visual Studio professional 2022
After installing Visual Studio Professional 2022, I was trying to install data tools for SSIS development and suddenly this message appeared "The installation of this Visual Studio instance is not completed. You may need to restart your machine to complete installation." Restarting Visual studio is not solving problem and message remains.
enter image description here
I have tried restarting my Visual studio instance as well as repair option but it did not work.

I was using an offline installer and couldn't simply re-run the Visual Studio Installer you can edit devenv.isolation.ini and change the last line to read SetupFinished=true. It will detect your trickery and complain, but at least it will launch again.

you have to install Microsoft.DataTools.ReportingServices first and then install Microsoft.DataTools.IntegrationServices
